# AngularJS performs an OPTIONS HTTP request for a cross-origin resource => error 401

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-services, rest, cors

I'm trying to use $resource to get datas from a REST web service.

here is my code :

```js
    return $resource('http://serverURL', {}, {

                getQuartiers: {
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers:  {
                             'Authorization': 'Basic base64login:pseudostring',
                     },

                },


          });
```

The problem is that with headers like this, it's an option request that is send and i get an error 401 Unauthorized.
If i remove headers, it's a GET request.
But i need headers to send my Authorization string !

Otherwise the webservice is ok, either by going with chrome directly to the url => popup with login/pwd => correct datas at json format
or by using postman chrome extension, which send a GET request.

What's the matter ?

Comment: your header request seems OK, I have used some thing like this in my web api project. I thing problem is with your web server and not with your JS codes. check your back end codes.

Comment: go check out Cors. http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/. That's your problem atm. Its a preflight getting 401.

Comment: As using postman with an OPTION request works fine, i think it's not a server configuration problem !?

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to be handling the preflight `Options` *requests*.

Your Web API needs to respond to the `Options` request in order to confirm that it is indeed configured to support `CORS`.

To handle this, all you need to do is send an *empty response* back.

This extra check was added to ensure that old `APIs` that were designed to accept only `GET` and `POST` requests will not be exploited. Imagine sending a `DELETE` request to an `API` designed when this *verb* didn't exist. The outcome is *unpredictable* and the results might be *dangerous*.

Comment: I am not sureto understand...You talk about server config, isn't it ?
Actually the server send response :
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
etc

But it seems that my headers aren't correctly send :

Comment: Yes, that's on the server side, API configuration.

Comment: Usingpostman, the OPTION request header has this line : 
Authorization:Basic mystring
Using my code, it is instead :
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, authorization

So i think my headers are not sent correctly !?